# Access public exchange folder with contacts from windows 10 mobile

Tags: windows-10-mobile, exchange, windows-10

I'd like to share contacts (both external and internal ones) with all users in my organisation. All users own an exchange account in the same domain and use windows 10 mobile phones.

What I did so far is to create a public folder with all contacts using outlook on my desktop PC:

[image]

The other users are able to access those contacts from their desktop, but I can't access that public folder from the mobile devices.

The exchange setup works properly.

**Any way to get this to work, without copying all the contacts?**

Comment: I'm actually looking into the same issue at the moment. Is there any news on this, have been able to find a working solution? Regards
Chris

Comment: No, unfortunately no news - we can't get I to work with windows phones. As a side note: **it's no problem at all with Iphones**! Perhaps the microsoft guys should ask apple on how to implement exchange on mobile devices...

Comment: By the way, your question above should be a _comment_ on my original question, not an answer.

Comment: @nabulke A reputation score of 50 is needed in order to comment on other people's posts. This is why new users will often post a comment as an answer. In the future, please flag such posts for moderator attention, who can then convert the answer to a comment (as I have done now). Thank you!